# Why can't I measure electric potential from source to point according to this formula

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, charge

The formula for electric potential of points A and B in the presence of an electric field due to a point charge where $R_a$ and $R_b$ are the distances from source to point A and B respectively is:
$${V_{AB}}=kq\left({1\over{R_B}}-{1\over{R_A}}\right)$$
But this formula only works when you are measuring distances $R_a$ and $R_b\,\neq0$
I don't understand the physical meaning of the fact that $R_a$ and $R_b$ cannot be zero.

Comment: What happens when you actually put $R_a$ or $R_b$ equal to zero?

Comment: well you as can see in the formula you'd be dividing by zero

Comment: That's why. The potential gets arbitrarily large when you get closer to the charge. When one of your points is on the charge, the potential difference with another point would simply be infinite.

Comment: thank you already! what about opposite charges?

Comment: There's only one charge in the situation you've mentioned.

Comment: In the derivation that lead to your formula, it was assumed that the charge (and there is only one) is fixed at the origin.  $R_1$ and $R_2$ are distances to *field points*:  points in space between which the potential difference is desired.  There's nothing but emptiness at those points.

Comment: True! Sorry I'm a bit tired and just began learning electric potential. What just crossed my mind was the potential going to zero between two opposite charges getting closer together.

Comment: First I was asked to calculate the potential due to a proton's electric field at a point where there's also an electron. Then I thought well the distance must start at r=0 until the point where the electron is. Then I mixed potential and charge interactions. I know the right way is to find the potential by comparing to infinity, in other words by making $R_a$ go to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

In reality, "point charges" don't exist. When you get close enough, you find that charge is spread out in a little cloud - just think of the way electrons behave around the nucleus of an atom, or about the Heisenberg uncertainty principle.

Once you accept that there is no such thing as a "point source", but instead everything is a "charge cloud" of finite size, then the singularity goes away. Imagine for a moment two "charge clouds", each of small radius $r$ and with total charge $Q$. Now the charge *density* at a given point scales with $\frac{Q}{r^3}$ , and if you now look at the potential between any two points, you see that since the charge in a volume element goes down with the dimension of that element cubed, you don't end up with a singularity.

That's how an apparent paradox like this can be resolved. Do you need to see the rest of the math, or is it clear like this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Where should I picture the two points in your example?

Comment: The two clouds can now overlap. Even if they overlap perfectly, the potential will not become infinite.

Comment: I'm actually interested in the formula of the potential between two points in your example!

Comment: OK - I don't have time now. Will try to do it later.

Comment: take your time!